# Как подключить протокол к Picker View, если он находится не на стартовой странице?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Такая проблема.
Нужно добавить протоколы(UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource) для Picker View, чтобы он начал работать. При этом сам Picker View находится не на стартовой странице, из-за чего при компилировании выдаётся ошибка, так как используется атрибут "self"(Это, как я понял).
Вот код:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
let array = ["One", "Two"]

override func viewDidLoad() {        
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource  = self
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "1club")

}

.......
```

Кто-то знает, как с этим бороться?

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Мажет добавите текст ошибки?

Comment: Конечно, вот такая:

->  0x1002425dc <+44>:  brk    #0x1
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yewijx2gyvsb193/App.zip?dl=0 вот файл для наглядности

Comment: на какой строке крешится?

Comment: pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource  = self
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "1club")

Вот эти три. Думаю, потому что использую self атрибут, а сам picker используется на второй странице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас там все очень запущено: все 7 конероллеров, которые есть в сториборде указаны как инстансы класса ViewController. таким образом, когда загружается первый, в нем нет `UIPickerView`. В результате когда вы пытаетесь в коде назначить делегат и датасурс у вас объект UIPickerView == nil, и получается ваша ошибка.

Как это исправить?

сделать 7 вью контроллеров для каждого экрана в сториборде, чтобы не было такой путаницы.

Comment: ДААААА! Спасибо!!!! Я 4 часа над этим сидел, а всё оказалось так просто! Теперь с чистой душой можно идти спать:) 

Хороших вам проектов, Максим:)

Comment: не забудьте принять ответ